# Why does this not cause an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have this piece of code. Logically this should go into an infinite render loop. But it remains stable and the output is that `a` and `b`, both, get printed together.

```
<div ng-if='hello'>
    <span ng-init='hello=false'>a</span>
</div>
<div ng-if='!hello'>
    <span ng-init='hello=true'>b</span>
</div>
```

This is not part of anything I am working on. It just popped up in my head and I could not find an answer to this anywhere.

**Edit**

I understand that in my above example as @dfsq pointed out, `ng-if` creates a new scope. So I changed the code a bit in [this example](https://codepen.io/muzic12freakzz/pen/gWyNmr). So here both `ng-if`s should refer to the same object. Why is it not going into a loop here?

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='appCtrl'>
    <div ng-if='object.hello'>
      <span ng-init='object.hello=false'>a</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-if='!object.hello'>
      <span ng-init='object.hello=true'>b</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  app.controller("appCtrl", [
    "$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.object = {};
      $scope.object.hello = true;
    }
  ]);
})();
```

Comment: ng-if creates a new scope, so they are not referring to the same instance

Answer (score 3):

> Logically this should go into an infinite render loop.

No, it should not. [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive creates new child scope, and because of that [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) modifies (creates) independent flag, which doesn't affect the one used in ngIf (parent scope `hello`).

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with a codepen link. Why is it still stable?

Answer (score 0):

As @dfsq mencioned, ng-if creates a new scope, if you want to create a infinite loop you should use something like:

```
<div ng-if='hello'>
    <span ng-init='$parent.hello=false'>a</span>
</div>
<div ng-if='!hello'>
    <span ng-init='$parent.hello=true'>b</span>
</div>
```